How big is the gap between Compact and Lie Groups? P-adic groups and continuity.
Recently i was reading in a book about representation theory a side note that suggested something like: Every compact group is a lie group.
So i started thinking about it and figured out, that its probably not true. But i am not 100% sure so here is my three questions:

My counterexample is: Take the field of p-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q_p}$ for any prime number p (its the completion of $(\mathbb{Q}, | \cdot |_p)$,for any further explanation check out the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number).
Because of the ultrametic property of the p-norm  and the trivial fact that $|x|_p=|-x|_p$, the closed Ball of unity $B:=\{ x \in \mathbb{Q}_p \mid |x|_p \leq 1\}$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Q}_p,+)$. Its easy to see that $|a+b-(x+y)|_p \leq \|(a,b) - (x,y) \|_1:= |a-x|_p+|b-y|_p$. Hence + is a continuous function. Trivially the map $x \mapsto -x$ is also lipschitz continuous. Hence $(B,+)$ is a topological group. Additionally B is compact (see for example the wikipedia link above) and hence a compact group. As much as i know B is not locally euclidean, because of some topological connection properties, what makes it impossible to be a lie group (because they are by definition topolocial manifolds). So my first question aims pretty much for a sufficient explanation/proof why B can not be locally euclidean.


While having this thoughts i was also thinking about the p-adic analogue of circle group $(S,\cdot)$ (while $S:=\{x\in \mathbb{Q}_p \mid |x|_p =1\}$ and $\cdot$ is the standart multiplication on $\mathbb{Q}_p$). Its easy to see, that this is a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Q}_p \setminus \{0\},\cdot)$ and i know that the multiplication map is also continuos. But is the inversion map  $\cdot : S \to S$ also continuous? I.e.: Is S a topolocial group?
Because this would make it to be a compact group as well. Its also probably not locally euclidean but i don't know a valid explanation. If someone knows an answer to this questions please let me know.
Returning to the original thoughts about this side note i mentioned in the beginning my last question must be:
How big is the gap between lie groups and compact groups? Or to be more precise: Is any locally euclidean compact group a (compact) lie group? I know this is probably true and strongly connected to (the solved) fifth problem of David Hilbert. But i struggle to understand the details (especially when it comes to the term manifold used in the corresponding wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_fifth_problem, because i know a different "definition" of a manifold. It seems to be used as locally euclideann here, but as much as i know it has to be second countable as well ...) I would be glad to here an explanation of an "expert" on this topic or a proof / counterexample.


Yes, also the profinite group $\Bbb Z_p$ is compact, but not a Lie group, see wikipedia

Regarding the side note that "suggested something like [...]", it's pretty much impossible for us to speculate what the author might have meant since we don't know what the author actually wrote.

I fixed it, this actually wasnt meant to be a precise question @LeeMosher. Anyways, feel free to speculate if you know things he could have meant. I sadly could not find this citation anymore, but it was very unprecise as well. The book was about representation theory.

The trouble is that the statement Every compact group is a lie group is flat out false, as you guess and is confirmed by @DietrichBurde. It's very often a losing game to speculate what actual statement might underlie a false restatement.

There is a thing called "$p$-adic Lie Groups", and obviously your examples are among those. If that is what was meant in your source is questionable.

Thank you for your guess @TorstenSchoeneberg!
Actually i think the author rather meant something like Mr. Yuan mentioned below.
As much as i know the representation theory of compact groups is (at least in the beginning) very similar to the finite case and some imaginary explanation would be that (at least for the beginning) 'it makes no difference' if you talk about representations of compact, or of compact lie groups. I don't know if that is true but it seems likely to me.

(All groups below assumed Hausdorff.)
As you've observed, it's not true that all compact groups are Lie groups. Your first counterexample is just $\mathbb{Z}_p$, and your second example is $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_p^{\times} \times \mathbb{Z}_p$ for $p \ge 3$ and something slightly more annoying when $p = 2$; this is proven using the $p$-adic logarithm. These groups are compact and  totally disconnected but not discrete, so can't be manifolds.
What is true is that every compact subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a Lie group; that is, every compact matrix group is a Lie group. This follows from the closed subgroup theorem. It should also be true that every compact locally Euclidean group is a Lie group, and this ought to have an easier proof than appealing to Hilbert's 5th problem because compactness ought to make things easier.
Generally, the Peter-Weyl theorem implies that every compact group is a pro-Lie group, in the sense that it is an inverse limit of Lie groups. The simplest examples that aren't Lie groups are the profinite groups, which are inverse limits of finite groups; this includes $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ above. These are all also totally disconnected. Then there are more complicated examples like solenoids, which are nontrivial inverse limits of circles; these are connected but not locally connected, so also can't be manifolds. Then there are funny examples like $\prod_n U(n)$, which is not locally Euclidean.

Thanks a lot!
You know any proof of "locally euclidean ( or even locally connected) compact group $\implies$ lie group?

@Simon: I think it should follow from Peter-Weyl (for locally Euclidean, I think the product of the unitary groups is a counterexample for locally connected) but I haven’t checked the details to see if it works.

Maybe to be precise, not "every compact subgroup of $GL_n$", but "...of $GL_n(\mathbb R)$, etc, ... :)

At the end of Bourbaki's volume about Lie Groups and Lie Algebras ch. IX (which is on  compact real Lie groups) there is an appendix on "structure of compact groups" that contains a bunch of results in this vein, starting with the one you mention that every compact group is an inverse limit of (real) Lie groups by Peter-Weyl.
